# Create a pandas column counter that successively counts 4 lines and 6 lines

Tags: python, pandas, counter

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple columns and I want to create a counter that successively counts 4 rows and 6 rows.
I would like it to look like the dataframe below:

| index | counter |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 8 | 2 |
| 9 | 2 |
| 10 | 3 |
| 11 | 3 |
| 12 | 3 |
| 13 | 3 |

As you can see, the first 4 values in `counter` column is 1, then next 6 values are 2, then again next 4 values are 3.

Comment: what are the definitions of 4 lines and 6 lines?  your question is very ambiguous. all I can see is there are 4 rows with value 1, followed by 6 with value 2, followed by 4 with value 3.  Not idea how this relates to an input dataframe

Comment: Sorry, I added an index column to make it clearer.
For example, if I have a dataframe, from the index I want to create a counter that increments by 1 when it reads 4 rows, then increments by 1 again when it reads 6 rows, then increments by 1 when it reads 4 rows (then by 1 again for 6 rows) and so on until the last row of my dataframe. Is this clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit clear after edit, you can create an empty list and a counter variable, then iterate on the range of number of rows incrementing it by 10 i.e. (4+6), then at each iteration, create the required lists of length 4 and 6 with counter and counter+1, add it to the resulting list.
Finally take the slice from result list first df.shape[0] values (because it may have few more values than df.shape[0]), and assign it to the new column df['counter'].

```py
result = []
counter = 1
for i in range(0, df.shape[0], 10):
    result += [counter]*4
    counter += 1
    result += [counter]*6
    counter += 1

df['counter'] = result[:df.shape[0]]
    
# result [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
    index  counter
0       0        1
1       1        1
2       2        1
3       3        1
4       4        2
5       5        2
6       6        2
7       7        2
8       8        2
9       9        2
10     10        3
11     11        3
12     12        3
13     13        3
```